# How to go back to the parent Fragment using webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-fragments

I have used fragments here. But I cannot go back to the parent.
 Swipeactivitydefault.java

```
 package com.pokhara.nepal;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.pokhara.nepal.json.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class Swipeactivitydefault extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_news);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }



}
```

Tab1.java

```
package com.pokhara.nepal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.news_activity_child, container, false);

        webView = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());

        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.tipfortechs.com/mobile");
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        return ll;

    }

}
```

Tab2.java and Tab3.java are also same as Tab 1

Just wanted to make three tabs.

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.pokhara.nepal.json;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.pokhara.nepal.Ekantipur;
import com.pokhara.nepal.HimalayaTimes;
import com.pokhara.nepal.NepalNews;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new Tab2();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new Tab3();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

news_activity_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Help me Please!!! I want to go back to the parent fragment after opening the link from that webview.

I know there are many answer out there. The one was overiding the back button. But I donot know how to implement. I am new to this. So, can somebody help me with the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.getParent().onBackPressed();
}
```

write onBackPressed() override method on tab1/tab2/tab3 fragment pages. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with `webview` but I have worked with tabbed fragments.

From my experience with tabbed fragments, one way to go would be to implement a method on the main activity that "exposes your viewpager functionality" and swtiches to a desired fragment. For example:

```
public void showTab(int n) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(n);
}
```

Then, within the fragment you want to trigger the transition to the other fragment, you just get the reference to the acitivy and tell it to show the tab you want.

```
Swipeactivitydefault m = (Swipeactivitydefault )getActivity();
m.showTab(1);
```