# Need a source code for Swipe tab + fixed tab with webview

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, tabs, android-fragments

I know there are many source code out there which provide the source code for swipe tab + fixed tab with web view.

But there is a problem with those source code. In the one of the tab one webpage is loaded. I click on the link then I go to another webpage. Now I want to go back to the primary link, that means the first webpage that was loaded, but the application exist. I have I used the source code from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529770/how-to-go-back-to-the-parent-fragment-using-webview)

I am new to android programming so it would be nice if someone who has similar source code and could give me their source code. I can not figure out how to go to primary fragment. I have tired to override the back button. But it does not seems to work.